# Posting JSON from PHP to Android issue

Tags: php, android, json

Hello i am currently having an issue sending a JSON object from my PHP to an Android device.
I have done this before with another person and it worked fine but now it does not seem to work.

It is a simple login script.  It should return the user's data or "false" based on whether the login email and password entered are correct.

The response is visible when tried in a browser but according to my colleague, he gets an empty array when viewing on his android development machine.

This is the php code:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    include('functions.php');
    include('password_hash_lib/password.php');

    if (!isset($_REQUEST["device"]))
    {
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];
        try
        {
            if (authenticate($Email, $Password))
            {
                echo "true";
            }
            else {
                echo "false";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else if (isset($_REQUEST["device"]))
    {
        $device = $_REQUEST['device'];
        $Email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $Password = $_REQUEST['password'];

        if ($device == 'mobi')
        {   
            try
            {
               if (authenticate($Email, $Password))
               {
                  $curruser = explode("+", $_SESSION['sess_user_auth']);

                  $arr = new ArrayObject(Array(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);  
                  $arr->userid = $curruser[0];
                  $arr->email = $curruser[1];
                  $arr->fullname = $curruser[2];
                  $arr->displaypic = $curruser[3];
                  $arr->displayname = $curruser[4];

                  echo str_replace("\\", "", json_encode((object) $arr));        
               }
               else {
                  echo "false";
               }
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
               echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

This is the android code my colleague wrote:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
boolean status=false;
LoginMgr lmgr=new LoginMgr(getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext());
try {
HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget=new HttpGet("http://www.xxxxx.com/login.php?device=mobi&email=xxxxxx@gmail.com&password=xxxxxxx

");
HttpResponse response= httpclient.execute(httpget);
int statuscode=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(statuscode==200){
InputStream is=response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
final StringBuilder stringbuild= new StringBuilder();
String curr_line;
if((curr_line=br.readLine())!=null){
stringbuild.append(curr_line);
String jsonstr=stringbuild.toString();
getSherlockActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), stringbuild.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
}
});
if(!jsonstr.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
JSONObject job=new JSONObject(jsonstr);
String str=job.getString("3").replace("\\/","/");
String image="http://www.xxxxx.com/img/timthumb.php?&h=50&w=50&src=

"+str;
lmgr.loginUser(new Login(job.getString("0"),job.getString("4"),job.getString("1"),image));
status=true;
JSONObject job=new JSONObject(jsonstr);
if(job.getString("success").equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
lmgr.loginUser(new Login(job.getString("userid"),job.getString("username"),job.getString("useremail"),job.getString("userimage")));
status=true;
}   
}
}
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
return status;
}
```

I have tried using return instead of echo in my code but that still did not work.  There were no errors just an empty array.

Comment: Why are you removing backslashes from the json_encode?

Comment: Because there is a url in the returned array, and the json_encode appears to add backslashes to escape certain characters.

Comment: But it is no longer valid json. You can't decode it anymore.

Comment: @blank: don't mess with JSON. You **NEVER** directly modify a json string, because what you're doing is introducing javascript syntax errors.

Comment: Hello i tried all your suggestions but none worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. Try to be consistent in what your script returns. It must always returns the same kind of data (`JSON`) even if it fails.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('functions.php');
include('password_hash_lib/password.php');

if (!isset($_REQUEST["device"]))
{
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    try
    {
        if (authenticate($Email, $Password)) echo json_encode(array('auth' => true));
        else echo json_encode(array('auth' => false));
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
}
else if (isset($_REQUEST["device"]))
{
    $device = $_REQUEST['device'];
    $Email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $Password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    if ($device == 'mobi')
    {
        try
        {
            if (authenticate($Email, $Password))
            {
                $curruser = explode("+", $_SESSION['sess_user_auth']);

                $json = array();
                $json['userid'] = $curruser[0];
                $json['email'] = $curruser[1];
                $json['fullname'] = $curruser[2];
                $json['displaypic'] = $curruser[3];
                $json['displayname'] = $curruser[4];
                echo json_encode($json);        
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode(array('auth' => false));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Based on your last update, you've got some mistakes in your Android code. I've tried to improve it but I haven't tested it.

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    boolean status = false;
    LoginMgr lmgr = new LoginMgr(getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext());
    try
    {
        // Connect to the remote server
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.xxxxx.com/login.php?device=mobi&email=xxxxxx@gmail.com&password=xxxxxxx");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        int statuscode=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(statuscode==200)
        {
            // Read response
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            final StringBuilder stringbuild= new StringBuilder();
            String curr_line = null;
            while ((curr_line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringbuild.append(curr_line);
            }

            getSherlockActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), stringbuild.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }
            });

            // Parse response to JSON
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject( stringbuild.toString() );
            if (json.has("auth"))
            {
                if (json.getBoolean("auth"))
                {
                    // Authentificate with success
                    getSherlockActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // In this case, authentification has failed
                    getSherlockActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Wrong user credentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else if (json.has("userid"))
            {
                String userid = json.getString("userid");
                String email = json.getString("email");
                String fullname = json.getString("fullname");
                String displaypic = json.getString("displaypic").replace("\\/","/");
                String displayname = json.getString("displayname");

                // In this case, we got some data about the user
                String image = "http://www.xxxxx.com/img/timthumb.php?&h=50&w=50&src=" + displaypic;
                lmgr.loginUser(new Login(json.getString("0"), json.getString("4"), json.getString("1"), image));
                status = true;
                JSONObject job = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                if(job.getString("success").equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                {
                    lmgr.loginUser(new Login(userid, fullname, email, displaypic));
                    status = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: I just edited my post and added the android script as you requested.

Comment: Thank you i will try it out, also could you please tell me the mistakes that were made and how you corrected them and why? Just so that they do not happen again. :)

Comment: When you read the server response, you must loop on `readLine`, in your code you just read it once. Also, you were parsing the `json` 3 or 4 times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Replace : `echo str_replace("\\", "", json_encode((object) $arr));`

By this : `echo json_encode(array('user'=>$arr));`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I changed HttpGet to HttpPost and it worked. Hope this helps